# How to use define in php

Tags: php

I've an array with some key value pair this re-written in number of places in my whole project. So, i would like to define at one place and use it.

The array is 
`array('isValid'=>'false','message'=>'Invalid login credentials, please try again');`

I tried this way, but it didn't worked
`define ('kCheckValidUserSuccessResponse',array('isValid'=>'false','message'=>'Invalid login credentials, please try again'));`

defining the array at the top and use it, but some how the value is not available when i echoed it.
echo `kCheckValidUserSuccessResponse`;

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants may only evaluate to scalar values

```
class Error {



public $my_error1 = array(
        'isValid'=>'false',
        'message'=>'Invalid login credentials, please try again'
    );

}


$error = new Error();

print_r($error->my_error1);
```

from that you can call the error in any of your code
be familiar also with the OOP programming

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use an array in `define`. Quote [from the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php):

> only scalar and null values are allowed. Scalar values are integer, float, string or boolean values.

If you want to reuse the array just store it in a regular variable:

```
$kCheckValidUserSuccessResponse = array('isValid'=>'false','message'=>'Invalid login credentials, please try again');
```

Be aware of the variable scope. If you want to use it inside a function you need to pull it inside with `global`:

```
global $kCheckValidUserSuccessResponse;
```

Alternatively you can store it as a static value inside a class.

```
class MyMessages {
  static $kCheckValidUserSuccessResponse = array('isValid'=>'false','message'=>'Invalid login credentials, please try again');
}
```

Then you can access it like this, regardless of the variable scope:

```
MyMessages::kCheckValidUserSuccessResponse
```

Answer (score 1):

define

```
  Defines a named constant, but not define a variable.
```

eg.

```
<?php
    define('PI', 3.14);
    define('PASSWORD', '123456');

    echo PI;
    echo PASSWORD;
```

Comment: This is the definition of the keyword, not an example of how to use it

Answer (score 1):

If it is just about leaving the text messages all in one place ( and to help with multilanguage support ) i would do:

```
define('INVALID_LOGIN_MESSAGE','Invalid login credentials, please try again');
define('INVALID_LOGIN_VALID','false');
```

later in the software....

```
array('isValid'=> INVALID_LOGIN_VALID ,'message'=> INVALID_LOGIN_MESSAGE);
```